# pcl::MovingLeastSquares eigen error under QT5

Tags: c++, qt5, point-cloud-library, eigen3

I followed tutorials on Ubuntu 16.04 with PCL 1.9.1 compiled from source. 
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/resampling.php#moving-least-squares

It works well on IDE Clion ubuntu 16.04,but gets Errors on IDE QT5 .
It's interesting , just the same computer and the same package version.
Here is the code:

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      // Load input file into a PointCloud<T> with an appropriate type
      PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new PointCloud<PointXYZ> ());
      pcl::io::loadPCDFile (argv[1], *cloud);

      // Create a KD-Tree
      pcl::search::KdTree<PointXYZ>::Ptr
        tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<PointXYZ>);

      // Output has the PointNormal type
      // in order to store the normals calculated by MLS
      PointCloud<PointNormal> mls_points;

      // Init object (second point type is for the normals, even if unused)
      pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal> mls;

      mls.setComputeNormals (true);

      // Set parameters
      mls.setInputCloud (cloud);
      mls.setPolynomialFit (true);
      mls.setSearchMethod (tree);
      mls.setSearchRadius (0.03);

      // Reconstruct CRASH IN LINE BELOW
      mls.process (mls_points);

      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Here is the gdb info:

```
1  _mm256_store_pd(double *, double __vector(4))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   avxintrin.h          842 0x7f91e383057f 
    2  Eigen::internal::pstore<double, double __vector(4)>(double *, double __vector(4) const&)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PacketMath.h         244 0x7f91e383057f 
    3  Eigen::internal::pstoret<double, double __vector(4), 32>(double *, double __vector(4) const&)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   GenericPacketMath.h  486 0x7f91e383057f 
    4  Eigen::internal::assign_op<double>::assignPacket<32, double __vector(4)>(double *, double __vector(4) const&) const                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             AssignmentFunctors.h 28  0x7f91e383057f 
    5  Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double>, 0>::assignPacket<32, 0, double __vector(4)>(long, long)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               AssignEvaluator.h    592 0x7f91e383057f 
    6  Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double>, 0>::assignPacketByOuterInner<32, 0, double __vector(4)>(long, long)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   AssignEvaluator.h    606 0x7f91e383057f 
    7  Eigen::internal::dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::internal::generic_dense_assignment_kernel<Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>>, Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double>, 0>, 4, 0>::run                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 AssignEvaluator.h    514 0x7f91e383057f 
    8  Eigen::internal::call_dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double>>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    AssignEvaluator.h    653 0x7f91e383057f 
    9  Eigen::internal::Assignment<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double>, Eigen::internal::Dense2Dense, double>::run                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         AssignEvaluator.h    790 0x7f91e383057f 
    10 Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double>>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      AssignEvaluator.h    747 0x7f91e383057f 
    11 Eigen::internal::call_assignment<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double>>(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>&, Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1> const&, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double> const&, Eigen::internal::enable_if<!Eigen::internal::evaluator_assume_aliasing<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>, Eigen::internal::evaluator_traits<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>>::Shape>::value, void *>::type) AssignEvaluator.h    712 0x7f91e38d0739 
    12 Eigen::internal::call_assignment<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   AssignEvaluator.h    693 0x7f91e38d0739 
    13 Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>>::_set<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       PlainObjectBase.h    682 0x7f91e38d0739 
    14 Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>::operator=<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::DiagonalWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, 1>>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Matrix.h             225 0x7f91e38d0739 
    15 pcl::MLSResult::computeMLSSurface<pcl::PointXYZ>(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const&, int, std::vector<int> const&, double, int, boost::function<double (double)>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            mls.hpp              821 0x7f91e38d0739 
    16 pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal>::computeMLSPointNormal                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 mls.hpp              181 0x7f91e38e6716 
    17 _ZN3pcl18MovingLeastSquaresINS_8PointXYZENS_11PointNormalEE17performProcessingERNS_10PointCloudIS2_EE._omp_fn.10(void)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          mls.hpp              330 0x7f91e38e6d98 
    18 GOMP_parallel                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0x7f91dfc00cbf 
    19 pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal>::performProcessing                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     mls.hpp              297 0x7f91e397e94b 
    20 pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal>::process                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               mls.hpp              144 0x7f91e38367b0 
    21 main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            main.cpp             49  0x40cf72
```

Any help here would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance .

**[SOLVED]**
Release mode

Comment: [SOLVED] Release mode will solve this problem

Comment: you should really take a second look because compilation problems simply don't vanish by making a release build.  In fact, at best they are only brushed bellow the proverbial carpet.